# React Native FlashList

Tags: react-native, flash-list

I just started exploring the FlashList component and I came across a problem.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXr4b.jpg)
I'm following their approach of SectionList but I want to achive a card like list but this is rendering the items one by one so each item is a card on it's own. Does anybody knows how can I make each group one card?

Is this

```
expenses?.map((group: any) => (
  <Fragment key={group.date}>
    <Animated.Text
      entering={FadeIn}
      exiting={FadeOut}
      layout={transition}
      style={{
        color: Colours[colourScheme ?? "dark"].textLight,
        width: "100%",
        marginTop: Sizes.xSmall,
      }}
    >
      {group.date}
    </Animated.Text>
    <Animated.View
      style={styles(Colours[colourScheme ?? "dark"]).container}
      layout={transition}
    >
      <FlashList
        data={group.expenses}
        renderItem={renderExpenses}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        estimatedItemSize={70}
      />
    </Animated.View>
  </Fragment>
```

a better approach with this data

```
const expensesGroups = expenseQuery.data
? Object.values(
    expenseQuery.data?.reduce((spd, item) => {
      var today = moment(new Date(item.expenseDate.split("T")[0])).format(
        "DD MMMM YYYY"
      );
      if (!spd[today]) {
        spd[today] = {
          date: today,
          expenses: [],
        };
      }
      spd[today].expenses.push(item);
      return spd;
    }, [])
  )
: [];
```

or it defeats the whole point of FlashList?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate **SectionList** component using FlashList, your data array needs to look different. It is still a flat array of items.

So in regular FlashList implementation like a **FlatList**  you have an array like this:

```
const data = [{...card0}, {...card1}, {...card2}]
```

If you want to implement **SectionList** your data array needs to look like:

```
const data = [{
    title: '', type: 0
}, 
{
    ...card0, type: 1
}, 
{
    ....card1, type: 1
}, 
{
    title: '', type: 0
}, 
{
    ...card2, type: 1
}]
```

And your **FlashList Component**:

```
const ContactsFlashList = () => {
  return (
    <FlashList
      data={contacts}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        if (item.type === 0) {
          // Rendering header
          return <Text style={styles.header}>{item}</Text>;
        } else {
          // Render item
          return <Text>{item.firstName}</Text>;
        }
      }}
      getItemType={(item) => {
        // To achieve better performance, specify the type based on the item
        return item.type === 0 ? "sectionHeader": "row";
      }}
      estimatedItemSize={100}
    />
  );
};
```

https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/guides/section-list

Then inside your renderItem function, you can do something like this:

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        if (item.type === 0) {
          // Rendering header
            return <Text style={styles.header}>{item}</Text>;
        } else {
          // Render item
            const prevItem = index > 0 ? data[index - 1] : null;
            const nextItem = index < data.length - 1 ? data[index + 1] : null;
            let borderStyles = {}
            if (prevItem !== null && prevItem.type === 0) {
                borderStyles = {
                    borderTopLeftCornerRadius = 8
                    borderTopRightCornerRadius = 8
                }
            }
            if (nextItem !== null && nextItem.type === 0) {
                borderStyles = {
                    borderBottomLeftCornerRadius = 8
                    borderBottomRightCornerRadius = 8
                }
            }
                // apply styles.
          return <Text>{item.firstName}</Text>;
        }
      }}
```

Comment: As I said I have done everything as they do. My problem is that because it renders each item individually I cant have a grouped card layout and instead I get a card for each item separate just like the screenshot

Comment: Oh so your problem is the border ?

Comment: Exactly I want the grouped items to be displayed as one card not one card for each

Comment: I've edit the answer, please check again, also I wrote it directly in StackOverflow so it might have typos :)

Comment: This doesnt work because FlashList renders the items one by one. Thats why Im having this problem. I want to use FlashList because they say it has better performance but in terms of implementation FlatList and SectionList are better in my opinion

Comment: Can you share what exactly it is not working? What is your result and what is the expected result. Share your code if possible. FlashList can do everything Flat/SectionList can do.

Comment: No I just made some adjustments and it worked. Thanks but my question here is is it really worth it? I mean we added some extra calculations and stuff where in SectionList are not needed I guess (unless if I'm wrong). Does FlashList really improves performance that much?

Comment: Your question is far from is FlashList worth it. And yes it is worth it, if you need to render a big list.

Comment: I've added some of my previous code in my question